# Вывести пустой массив при при отсутствии переменной

Tags: python, массивы, функции

Решаю задачки на codewars. Вот условие:

> We want an array, but not just any old array, an array with contents!
> Write a function that produces an array with the numbers 0 to N-1 in > it.
>
> For example, the following code will result in an array containing the numbers 0 to 4:
>
> ```
> arr(5) // => [0,1,2,3,4]
> ```
>
> Note: The parameter is optional. So you have to give it a default value.

Не могу допенькать как вывести при отсутствии переменной, пустой массив []

Вот мой код:

```
def arr(n):
    # [ the numbers 0 to N-1 ]
    z = []
    if not n:
        return (z)
    for i in range(n):
        z.append(i)
    return (z)
```

Заранее спасибо за уделенное время!

Comment: А вообще непонятно, зачем так сложно, можно просто `return list(range(n))` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто дать параметру n значение по умолчанию 0:

```
def arr(n = 0):
```

И небольшой совет: `return` - не функция, можно писать без скобок: `return z`

И ещё один совет по сокращению кода: всю функцию можно уместить в две строчки:

```
def arr(n = 0):
    return [i for i in range(n)]
```

или как ранее было подмечено:

```
def arr(n = 0):
    return list(range(n))
```

Comment: test.assert_equals(arr(4), [0,1,2,3])
        test.assert_equals(arr(0), [])
        test.assert_equals(arr(), [])

Comment: последняя строка проверочного кода не проходит, а с нулевым значением все норм